# Where is better to store html pages?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Where is better to store html pages in the database or in the files itself?

if I have to many files:

user/login.php

user/register.php

user/somethingElse.php

articles/index.php

articles/view.php

articles/somethingElse.php

and all the code store there, or to store those pages as html in the database and then render it to only one file content.php?

Comment: You need to provide more details.

Comment: How do you define `better`? Its such a subjective term

Comment: i mean a more flexible way

Comment: Usually even a big CMS would store only content and settings in a database, but not the code itself. Code resides on file system mostly

Comment: i have 3 files: header.php, content.php, footer.php, and i think if i will render all the html from the database to content.php it will be a good idea or bad?

Comment: Using a database will be slightly slower because you have to make a connection to the database. Also, you cannot use an IDE for editing your code. I recommend using PHP files and have content.php fetch the proper PHP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can say that storing HTML into files is much better than DB because

```
1)For retrieving data also you need to perform DB operations as well,so it may stuck DB somewhere when load is become a 'real load' to operate DB
2)A DB can crash but a file cont much when compared to DB
3)If you want to change the HTML you need to perform agian update operation for that which makes big issue for an developer to work 
4)And also in DB you need to store HTML tags,other things using 'htmlentities' which causes conflict
```

Comment: yep, looks like you're right

Answer (score 0):

You can either store HTML code in your PHP files, or use HTML files and have PHP fetch those files.

Answer (score 0):

The way i like to do it is to keep as much of the HTML as possible in my root:/index.php-file and then load the files i need depending on what page an user wanna see.

F.x. user wanna see articles i send them to index.php?page=articles, load the page layout and include("articles/index.php"); This will also let you use htaccess to make the url's look at lot better.

But as a general rule dont keep HTML-code in your SQL, unless it's user-submitet stuff.